# APK Signature Scheme v1 vs APK Signature Scheme v2/v3

Tags: android, digital-signature, attack-vector

What are the security implications of using the APK Signature Scheme v1 instead of the APK Signature Scheme v2/v3? Are there any additional attack vectors for v1 except for direct attack vectors in an APK verifier? With direct attack vectors mean things like DoS directly in the APK verifier.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote the [official docs](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning#v1):

> v1 signatures do not protect some parts of the APK, such as ZIP metadata. The APK verifier needs to process lots of untrusted (not yet verified) data structures and then discard data not covered by the signatures. This offers a sizeable attack surface. Moreover, the APK verifier must uncompress all compressed entries, consuming more time and memory. To address these issues, Android 7.0 introduced APK Signature Scheme v2.

So yes, JAR signing (v1 signature) does have additional attack vector: malicious mangling of the metadata, or of compressed (signed) entries. For example, uncompressing a specially forged entry, which occurs in trusted context, could cause dangerous side-effects for your system.